# Mapping file into memory and writing beyong end of file

Tags: c, linux, file-io, linux-kernel, memory-mapped-files

I'm experimenting with memory mapped file in Linux and have a question of what actually going on when mapping the same file from different processes and writing beyond the end of file.

I created a file with vim by hand and wrote 2 bytes in there:

```
$ cat test_mmap
aa
```

Then I wrote 2 very simple programs.

The first program maps the file and modifies the mapping without `msync` and `munmap`.

`writer.c`:

```
int main(void){
    int fd = open("/tmp/test_mmap", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
    char *mapped_region = mmap(NULL, sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    mapped_region[0] = '0';
    mapped_region[1] = '1';
    mapped_region[2] = '2';
    mapped_region[3] = '3';
    mapped_region[4] = '4';
    mapped_region[5] = '5';
}
```

The second one is reading the mapping.

`reader.c`:

```
int main(void){
    int fd = open("/tmp/test_mmap", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
    char *mapped_region = mmap(NULL, sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    printf("%c\n", mapped_region[0]);
    printf("%c\n", mapped_region[1]);
    printf("%c\n", mapped_region[2]);
    printf("%c\n", mapped_region[3]);
    printf("%c\n", mapped_region[4]);
    printf("%c\n", mapped_region[5]);
}
```

So I ran

```
$ ./writer && ./reader && cat /tmp/test/test_mmap
0
1
2
3
4
5
012
```

This means that any data written beyond the end of file is preserved in the mapping for some time (although it is not written out to the file) and if another process consequently maps the same region the data written beyond are not zeroed as specified in the [man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> A file is mapped in multiples of the page size.  For a file that is not
>   a multiple of the page size, the remaining memory is zeroed when
>   mapped, and writes to that region are not written out to the file.

Running reader with `perf -e major-faults ./reader` shows that

```
0      major-faults
```

meaning that no pages are read from the disk. Also looking at the `/proc/<pid_writer>/smaps` I observed that the page is marked as dirty and private (even though the mapping was create with `MAP_SHARED` flag):

```
7fc80f279000-7fc80f27a000 -w-s 00000000 fd:00 6057290   /tmp/test_mmap
Shared_Clean:          0 kB                                                                                                                                                                                        
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB                                                                                                                                                                                        
Private_Clean:         0 kB                                                                                                                                                                                        
Private_Dirty:         4 kB
```

If I ran the reader process after some time (what time is required to wait?) I observed that

```
$ ./reader
0
1
2
```

***Question:*** Is it correct and documented somewhere that if one process modifies mapping beyond the end of the file the page is marked as dirty and as long as the page is dirty and another process maps the same region of the same file the data written by the process before is not zeroed and preserved as is for a while?

Comment: At a guess, if a part of a file is already mapped to a physical page, any process that also maps that file will get that same physical page mapped into its address space.  So any change to that page (whether part of the file or past the end) will be visible to all processes that have mapped the file.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yeah, that's what can be observed. But does't that contradict to what is specified in the [man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). _For a file that is not a multiple of the page size, the remaining memory is zeroed when mapped_

Comment: @wildplasser Could you please expand a bit what you mean by _You map what you map_. I could guess that even if the page is dirty it is considered as a part of the file. And when it is cleaned the data beyond EOF is zeroed. Correct?

Comment: Not really.  The file page has already been mapped (even if into a different process), so the extra bytes do not need to be not zeroed.

Comment: Page==dirty is completely irrelevant here.You get the mapping (upto the current size, at the time of mmapping)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Good point, did not think about it, really.

Comment: @wildplasser Yeah, now I see. The wording of the man-page is confusing a bit: _`mmap()` creates  a  **new**  mapping in the virtual address space of the calling process_. So at first I interpreted it as each time `mmap` is called a new mapping is created (even if the region was already mapped)

Comment: Since the posted code fails to check the status for the system calls for `mmap()` and `open()` anything might have happened and we will never know.  Also, Both the calls to `open()` have the `O_CREAT` parameter, bit the file already exists so the calls to `open()` probably failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitive reference in these matters is POSIX, which in its rationale section for mmap has to say:

> The mmap() function can be used to map a region of memory that is
>   larger than the current size of the object. *[... snip discussion on
>   sending SIGBUS if possible, i.e. when accessing a page beyond the end
>   of the file ...]* written data may be lost and read data may not
>   reflect actual data in the object.

So, POSIX says that doing this can result in lost data. Also, the portability is questionable at best (think about no-MMU systems, the interaction with hugepages, platforms with different pagesizes...)

Comment: It seems SIGBUS is raised when the file length is multiple of page size and then when trying to access some region beyond it page fault handler raises the signal (It is just my guess from the observable behavior on Linux)